# Search in a multidimensional array and get an index

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have an array like that:

```
printr_($photos);
======

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [path] => site:photos/photo-1.jpg
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [PhotoTitle] => Mega title
                    [PhotoDate] => 2015
                    [FlickrURL] => xxx
                    [Portrait] => 
                    [slug] => mega-title
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [path] => site:photos/photo-2.jpg
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [PhotoTitle] => Photo title
                    [PhotoDate] => 2001
                    [FlickrURL] => xxx
                    [Portrait] => 
                    [slug] => photo-title
                )

        )

...
```

I would like to get the array index from a string (which is the slug from my browser current URL).
Tried that solution but I got an error (Undefined index: data […] on line 95)

```
/*
** Search in array
*/
function arraySearch($array, $field, $search){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if ($value[$field] === $search)
            return $key;
    }
    return false;
}

// Line 95
$photo_index = $photos[arraySearch($photos["data"], "slug", "mega-title")];
```

Comment: IF you want to get the index from an element why do you also pass the index itself?! Also do you always search with a photo-title ?

Comment: The array_search function returns only an index, then I search for that index in my $photos array which contains all my items. Is that wrong?

Comment: I don't get it: what is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: Since `$photos` has a numerical index in it's top level, I am not sure how you expect to find the proper index when your function returns a string.

Comment: I have two elements in my possession before searching: my $photos array which contains all the arrays with photos (like a database if you like) and my slug, from the current URL. What I'm looking for is from that slug, get the array containing the slug. That's all!

Comment: As was mentioned, `$photos["data"]` does not exist. `$photos[0]["data"]` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work PHP >= 5.5:

```
$key = array_search('mega-title', array_column(array_column($photos, 'data'), $slug));
$photo_index = $photos[$key];
```

Comment: I was also thinking exactly the same :) (congraze to 20k)

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123.  I've seen many answers/comments where we're on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The `$photos` variable does not have a key 'data', at least not by the print output. It has keys `1, 2, 3` etc.So `$photos["data"]` simply does not exist.

As to the search, I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, but I assume you want to get the index of the photo which `$field` in `data` equals `$search`, so that would be

```
/*
** Search in array
*/

function arraySearch($array, $field, $search){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if ($value["data"][$field] === $search)
            return $key;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and you would use it

```
$photo_index = $photos[arraySearch($photos, "slug", "mega-title")];
```